# How can I send some jsp forms without csrf token in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I am using `<csrf/>` tag in my spring security xml file for a web project. By this tag I have to send csrf token in each form used in the jsp page.

Spring security xml code:

```
    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login
    <!--login tags -->
    </>

    <csrf/>
    </http>
```

But there is a scenario where I don't want to send the csrf token for a particular form in a jsp page, How could I do that.

I used the following tag in my xml file

```
<http pattern="/specific_url/**">
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

and got error: "**cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'disabled' is not allowed to appear in element 'csrf'**"

Comment: Which version of Spring Security do you use? What xsd for the file above?

Comment: I think it's a matter of schema, you should ignore the error as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349881/403-errors-after-upgrading-to-spring-security-4-0-0

Comment: hello holmis83, i am using 3.2.4 version of jars for spring security.

Comment: Why do you not want CSRF there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spring Security version 3.2.x, the CSRF protection is disabled by default when using XML configuration. So just remove the `csrf` element from the config, and it will be off.

From version 4, CSRF protection is *enabled* by default, so if you upgrade you will need the snippet suggested in question.